# Group data using d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I try to reproduce [this example](http://www.d3noob.org/2014/07/d3js-multi-line-graph-with-automatic.html) of multipline graph using d3.
I state that I know very little d3, I just started using it.

I would get a graph that has the dates (1995, 1996, ..., 2010) on the x axis and the numerical values from 0 to 3000 on the y axis.
The line representing the various categories of data in the csv.

This is part of my code:

```
// Get the data
d3.csv("./data/df_out.csv", function(error, data) {
    data.forEach(function(d) {
      d.year = d.year; //parseDate(d.year);
      d.value = +d.value;
    });

    // Scale the range of the data
    x.domain([1995, 2010]);
    y.domain([0, 3000]);

    // Nest the entries by death
    var dataNest = d3.nest()
        .key(function(d) { return d.death;})
        .entries(data);

    // Loop through each symbol / key
    dataNest.forEach(function(d) {
        svg.append("path")
            .attr("class", "line")
            .attr("d", valueline(d.values)); 
    });     
});
```

When I run it, I get the error:

**Error:  attribute d: Expected number, "MNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNL…".attrConstant @ d3.js:663(anonymous function) @ d3.js:962d3_selection_each @ d3.js:968d3_selectionPrototype.each @ d3.js:961d3_selectionPrototype.attr @ d3.js:652(anonymous function) @ script.js:56(anonymous function) @ script.js:53(anonymous function) @ d3.js:1996event @ d3.js:504respond @ d3.js:1949**

The problem is the `nest` function, I don't understand why.

Could someone help me?

Here the entire code: http://plnkr.co/edit/kiU1KwdvsC7e1rrjAuCM?p=preview.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly your CSV is incorrect:

```
",""year"",""death"",""value"""
"1,2003,""Acute poliomyelitis"",0"
"2,2006,""Acute poliomyelitis"",0"
"3,2007,""Acute poliomyelitis"",0"
"4,2008,""Acute poliomyelitis"",0"
"5,2009,""Acute poliomyelitis"",0"
"6,2010,""Acute poliomyelitis"",0"
"7,1995,""Acute poliomyelitis"",0"
"8,1996,""Acute poliomyelitis"",0"
"9,1997,""Acute poliomyelitis"",0"
"10,1998,""Acute poliomyelitis"",0"
"11,1999,""Acute poliomyelitis"",0"
"12,2000,""Acute poliomyelitis"",0"
"13,2001,""Acute poliomyelitis"",0"
"14,2002,""Acute poliomyelitis"",0"
```

It should have been (double quotes removed)

```
,year,death,value
1,2003,Acute poliomyelitis,0
2,2006,Acute poliomyelitis,0
3,2007,Acute poliomyelitis,0
4,2008,Acute poliomyelitis,0
5,2009,Acute poliomyelitis,0
6,2010,Acute poliomyelitis,0
7,1995,Acute poliomyelitis,0
8,1996,Acute poliomyelitis,0
9,1997,Acute poliomyelitis,0
10,1998,Acute poliomyelitis,0
11,1999,Acute poliomyelitis,0
12,2000,Acute poliomyelitis,0
13,2001,Acute poliomyelitis,0
14,2002,Acute poliomyelitis,0
```

Secondly,

You need to parse the date like this:

```
data.forEach(function(d) {
  d.year = parseDate(d.year);
  d.value = +d.value;
});
```

Thirdly

Set the x domain like this:

```
x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d){return d.year}));
```

Lastly before passing the line data sort your data w.r.t. years.

```
// Loop through each symbol / key
dataNest.forEach(function(d, i) {
  d.values = d.values.sort(function(a,b){return a.year -b.year});//sort by year
  svg.append("path")
        .attr("class", "line")
        .attr("d", valueline(d.values))
        .style("stroke", color(i)) ; 
});
```

working code [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/UXoU4CquOFklr27cw7IL?p=info)

Comment: Thanks for the help. Why I have to sort the data by year?

Comment: if the year is not sorted the line will go zig zag try commenting the line and see it for yourself the effect.